# Django + Gunicorn + SCRIPT_NAME

Tags: django, gunicorn

I have a number of django apps running off the same domain but am having problems getting SCRIPT_NAME to work properly with Gunicorn.

Example app paths:

- www.domain.com/app1
- www.domain.com/demo

**Scenario1:** I currently have each app running on Elastic Beanstalk and modify the apache config to deal with the SCRIPT_NAME side of things. This works.

**Scenario2:** I have been testing using AWS ECS/FARGATE and in that config I only have a container running Django/Gunicorn. There is no Apache/Nginx etc. I intend to just use Django/Gunicorn/Whitenoise/Cloudfront. **This is not working.** The SCRIPT_NAME value to make django work with sub paths is duplicating.

To simplify/troubleshoot I am running the code/commands below locally, so AWS is not involved. I have also created a bare bones/simple django app for testing.

My app page structure is like this:

- Home

  - Page1 Link `<a href="{% url 'demo:page1' %}">Page1</a>`

    - Home Link  `<a href="{% url 'demo:home' %}">Home</a>`
  - Page2 Link `<a href="{% url 'demo:page2' %}">Page2</a>`

    - Home Link  `<a href="{% url 'demo:home' %}">Home</a>`

Steps:

1. I launch the webserver:
   `gunicorn config.wsgi --env SCRIPT_NAME=demo -b 0.0.0.0:80 --keep-alive 20 --log-file=- --log-level debug --capture-output` (its running in a docker container)
2. I can go to `http://127.0.0.0:8000/demo`. It loads the app home page as expected.
3. The *Page1* link shows as `http://127.0.0.0:8000/demo/page1`, I click and it takes me as expected to *Page1*
4. The *Home* link shows as `http://127.0.0.0:8000/demo/demo/`. It has duplicated the SCRIPT_NAME and the link doesn't work.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Is this meant to work?

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace "SCRIPT_NAME=demo" with "SCRIPT_NAME=/demo" (note the additional slash) in your server launch command line.